# how to install amd gpu open source drivers

Tags: 16.04, graphics, video, radeon

I have a dell inspiron 5520  running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. MY laptop has a amd radeon hd 7000 series.How do i figure out wether my gpu is running or not ?. 
This is the output i got whil running `sudo xrandr`

```
    Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      60.00*+  40.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: The OSS drivers are prenistalled normaly, do you use the close source driver? Please speciffy what you are trying to accommplish. This question may be already asked and answered. Pleas use the sites search function. It might be marked as duplicate.

Comment: By close source driver do you mean flgrx? 16.04 doesn't support that anymore. Only open source drivers work I just want to know if drivers for my gpu comes pre installed with the os or wether I have to install them. I tried searching but couldn't find any clear answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are preinstalled. You don't need to worry.

Comment: Thank you.one more thing .... How do I know my gpu is working like I don't play high performance games I just play cs go or DoTA how do I know my gpu is running ?

Comment: you can check the output of `sudo xrandr` to see with driver is used currendly.

Comment: There are some limitations bassed around which generation a GPU has as yours is Pre GCN it should be best supported by the OSS driver anyway.

Comment: Cannot understand the output pls help

Comment: edit your question and copy the output in, so we can see it, to help you.